# Entity Framework Core use windows service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Currently in the process of building a multi tired application using EF Core for my data access layer and I feel like I'm running in to a problem and I'm not 100% certain I can use it at the moment.

Essentially I'm designing my application into the following components

- windows assembly
- asp.net mvc core web app
- windows service x2
- unit test

in good design I'm putting as much of my domain in my assembly so that I can reuse it as much as possible, but this is where I'm running into issues. I'm currently unable to use EF in my unit test app.

I am currently overriding OnConfiguring to set the database connection string but when I attempt to use the context in a unit testI continually get the following exception message: "Instance failure"

My context is dirt simple right now and only has one entity and looks as follows:

```
public partial class CdiContext : DbContext
{
    private string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    private bool IsService { get; set; }
    public CdiContext(string connectionString, bool isService)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        IsService = isService;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    }

    public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
 }
```

In an effort to rule out the unit test as the problem I've also created a simple console application and even it throws the same exception so I'm really lost as to how to proceed.

```
 CdiContext context =  new CdiContext(@"Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=herp-interface;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=herpaderp;Pooling=true", true);
 var regions = context.Regions.ToList();

 Console.ReadLine();
```

**The question is what am I doing that's wrong where I am unable to use a EF context from a windows assembly in any type of project aside from an ASP.NET Core MVC app?**

Comment: missed it could you make the question in BOLD, thx, also include the error

Comment: are you sure your connection string is valid?

Comment: Yup, I use the same string in my mvc app and there are no issues connecting there.

Comment: can you specify on which line / command the exception occurs and paste the exception?

Comment: Have you added your migrations? (assuming you're doing code-first)

Comment: migrations are not being used as a database already exists.

Comment: I've tried your code (with one of my own existing entity) and it works.

Comment: Remove the second \ character from your connection string. Your using the @ for verbatim string, no need to escape.

Comment: @ilans and jya  I can't believe I was blind to see the obvious. Now I fee like a tit for not seeing the obvious.

Comment: I had a feeling :)

Answer (score 5):

This error - **"Instance failure"** - occurs when you copy/paste the connection string from your aspnetcore app, and still have **escaped backslashes**.

Outside of ASP.Net Core, ie a console/windows service etc, the connection string in the app.config does not need to escape the backslashes.

EG

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS...
```

rather then

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS...
```